# how to replace video code with html code using php

Tags: php, html, tags, preg-replace

I want to replace some html tags using php

my string is:

```
some contents are before tags
<div class="videoPlayerCont">
    <div id="myElement">please wait...</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
            file: "http://mydomain.com/video/20140623.mp4",
            image: "",
            width: 500
        });
</script>
and some contents is after tags
```

Now i want like:

```
some contents are before tags
[video]http://mydomain.com/video/20140623.mp4[/video]
and some contents is after tags
```

please help me.
I don't Know how to use `preg_replace`

Comment: A. Why are you using `preg_replace`? B. Have you attempted it yourself?

Comment: where is this coming from? what are you trying to do (from a broader perspective)? Most people go the other way around.. want to replace a bbcode style tag with html..

Comment: I can not work with `preg_replace`

Comment: I think you're over-complicating this. Why are you doing it this way? What's your desired end result? This looks like it can be solved completely with JavaScript, but it's hard to say for sure without know more about what you're doing.

Comment: If you want to search for **html** and replace with **bbcode style** string then you should use a DOM Parser like [php.net/DOM](http://www.php.net/DOM).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you are doing this but anyway... You could use [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to safely and easily parse the HTML code:

1. Check if the div with class `videoPlayerCont` exists
2. If so, get the adjacent `script` element"s content using the `text` method
3. Search the extracted JS code with regular expression for the first URL